# how can I add -help for my own git external commands?

Tags: git

Say, I added my own `git myrun` command.

In my `$PATH`, I've got this file `git-myrun`

How/where can I add the help message so that, when  `git myrun -h` is invoked, it will print out the help message?

Comment: Same as you would in any shell script. Check if `-h` was passed, and print a help message if it is